# Using mongoid with map reduce on an enslaved model favors one mongodb slave

Tags: mapreduce, mongoid

I've got 4 mongodb slaves off of a master,  and running a map reduce frequently on data in an enslaved model seems to favor the first slave by a factor of 5x.